# MySQL: SELECT value WHERE subquery returns a wildcarded value

Tags: mysql, wildcard

Confusing title...my apologies.

What I've got is a table with two related rows.  I need to get the value of a column in one row based on the value of a column in another row.

Given the following postmeta table:

```
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| meta_id  | post_id    | meta_key                                          |  meta_value        |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| 6917     | 661        | member_categories_0_member_categories_name        | 11                 |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| 6918     | 661        | member_categories_0_member_categories_description | First description  |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| 6919     | 661        | member_categories_1_member_categories_name        | 12                 |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| 6920     | 661        | member_categories_1_member_categories_description | Second description |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to get the meta_value category description based on the meta_value category ID and the post_id.  For instance, if my category ID is 11 and my post_id is 661, I should get "First description".

I thought about using a subquery to get the meta_key corresponding with a meta_value of '11', but I don't know how to find the description based on the counter inside 'member_categories_x_member_categories_name'.

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the name of the meta_key.  I got as far as this simple query, which returns 'member_categories_0_member_categories_name'.  How do I use that value to find 'First description'?

```
    SELECT pm.meta_key 
    FROM postmeta pm
    WHERE pm.meta_value = "11"
    AND pm.post_id = 661
```

Here's the SQL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `postmeta` (
    `meta_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `post_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `meta_key` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `meta_value` LONGTEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
    INDEX `post_id` (`post_id`),
    INDEX `meta_key` (`meta_key`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=30814;

INSERT INTO `postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (6917, 661, 'member_categories_0_member_categories_name', '11');
INSERT INTO `postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (6918, 661, 'member_categories_0_member_categories_description', 'First description');
INSERT INTO `postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (6919, 661, 'member_categories_1_member_categories_name', '12');
INSERT INTO `postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (6920, 661, 'member_categories_1_member_categories_description', 'Second description');
```

Comment: You say that you can't control the value of the meta_key column. Do you at least know for sure that it will end with '_description' ?

Comment: can you please update your question with your desired result set?

Comment: @IanClelland, yes, the values will always be in the same pattern...only the counter will change.

Comment: @LuisSiquot, I clarified that in the question.  Thanks, it really wasn't very clear.

Comment: @IanClelland, I should mention that there are other values that match '%_name' and '%_description', so the full value should be matched 'member_categories_%_member_categories_description' & 'member_categories_%_member_categories_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but then, that table is so far from normalized that any answer short of scanning every row is going to be something like this:

```
SELECT pm2.meta_value 
  FROM postmeta pm1
  JOIN postmeta pm2
    ON pm1.post_id = pm2.post_id
   AND SUBSTRING(pm1.meta_key,1,LENGTH(pm1.meta_key)-5) = SUBSTRING(pm2.meta_key,1,LENGTH(pm2.meta_key)-12)
   AND pm1.meta_key like '%_name'
   AND pm2.meta_key like '%_description'
 WHERE pm1.meta_value = 11
   AND pm1.post_id = 661
```

The idea is to join the table to itself, linking rows that have the same post_id, and whose meta_key is 'similar' -- it needs to be exactly the same, except that one ends with `_name` and one ends with `_description`.

Comment: This looks promising but I'm getting an empty result set.  I've edited my question to include the SQL for the table in question.  Thanks!

Comment: I should mention that there are other values that match '%_name' and '%_description', so maybe the query should be edited to replace these two lines: 
AND pm1.meta_key like 'member_categories_%_member_categories_description'
   AND pm2.meta_key like 'member_categories_%_member_categories_name'

Comment: It looks like I forgot the starting string index in the SUBSTRING() call. I've fixed that now; give it a shot.

Comment: This works great!  Thanks!  For completeness I edited your answer to match the full meta_key value.

Answer (score 0):

This's raw, but quicker than extract the number from the string,

```
SELECT pm2.meta_key,  pm2.meta_value 
FROM postmeta pm, postmeta pm2
WHERE pm.meta_value = "11"
AND pm.post_id = 661
and pm.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
AND pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
and substring(pm.meta_key,30) = substring(pm2.meta_key,30)
```

I apologizes, I made some mistakes, follows the correct one:

```
SELECT pm2.meta_value 
FROM postmeta pm, postmeta pm2
WHERE pm.meta_value = "11" 
AND pm.post_id = 661
and pm.meta_id <> pm2.meta_id
AND pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
and substring(pm.meta_key,19,20) = substring(pm2.meta_key,19,20)
```

As I told this's **raw** but uses (IMHO) less CPU from DB and made a better uses of indexes. Of course this is safe *only* for 20 digits.

of course if you have more than 2 meta_key (name and description) you should add:

```
AND pm2.meta_key like '%_description'
AND pm.meta_key like '%_name'
```

This index is unuseful (meta_key is subject of elaboration):

```
INDEX `meta_key` (`meta_key`)
```

better add this one:

```
INDEX `idx_post_id_meta_value` (`post_id`,`meta_value`)
```

Comment: The constant '30' in there might break as soon as the integer in the meta_key column exceeds 9 -- I've added a solution which uses string length calculations to get around that restriction.

Comment: This gives me the 11 row: member_categories_0_member_categories_name || 11

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have fully understood what you want.

This gives the full "table", if you want to add a "where" clause you can add it at the end but for best performance, add inside the subqueries.

```
select
  n.*, d.meta_value as meta_value_descrip
from 
  (
   select left(meta_key, 34) as xjoin, p.*
   from postmeta p where right(meta_key, 4)  = 'name'
  ) as n
left join   -- or inner join
  (
   select left(meta_key, 34) as xjoin, p.*
   from postmeta p where right(meta_key, 11) = 'description'
   ) as d
on n.post_id = d.post_id and n.xjoin = d.xjoin
```

Comment: i have corrected a typo, and I have tested on mysql and works fine

Comment: "best performance" and "subqueries" should not stay in same sentence

Comment: @Ivan when a query has subquerys to make it better, the best you can do is filter the query and filter de subquerys too.

Comment: @LuisSiquot my critic is not about the missing conditions inside the subquery (you warn it) but the use of subqueries when you can do a simple join (as you can see in the other examples). About this question you can also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658501/join-query-or-subquery